# How can I access the "Your Books" account provided in QBOA via the API?

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I work for a company that builds products that integrate with QBO.
An issue that we ran into recently is that when accessing a customer's clients via the API, her "Your Books" account was missing.

I think the main problem is that the parent account and the "Your Books" account share the same account id. When we make the call via the API, it disregards the "Your Books" account since it is not technically a client.

Are there anyways around this?

It would not be an ideal user experience to request our users to create a special account to track their books, considering that all accounts aside from "Your Books" are paid for, while the former is complimentary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually figured this out and it was much simpler than I thought. Under the drop-down where you would normally choose your clients, there is a link that says 'Add App To Firm'. Once you click that, the list of clients disappears, leaving only the parent company. That will allow one to import the 'Your Books' account.